# Why did he call himself "The Mule?"

Tags: foundation

In the concluding few sentences of *Foundation and Empire*, the Mule says that:

> I call myself the Mule - but not because of my strength, obviously -

They do not finish the sentence. Earlier in the book some Foundation denizens theorised that it was because of his hard-working attitude to galactic conquest (which seems odd in itself), but this effectively disproves that. If it was not because of his strength, why did he name himself thus? I presume that it's implied but I have failed to make any inferences.

Comment: Hee haw! Hee haw!

Comment: I don't think that "namesake" is the right word here. Obviously the Mule's namesake is just a mule. What you are looking for is why he chose that to be his name. Maybe it should read, "How did the Mule choose his name?"

Comment: @TBear you're probably right, I did consider for a few seconds what word would be best to use because I wasn't sure.

Comment: I've removed the author tag (again), because we don't use them for questions about specific works as per [this meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7924/70236).

Comment: You know, a galaxy with a mind-controlling dictator is like the mule with a spinning wheel.

Comment: Because he's sterile.

Comment: Heh heh! _Mule._

Answer (score 127, accepted):

The Mule's name is self-chosen and refers to his [sterility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule)

> *"Secondly, **we did not know of your physical shortcomings, particularly
>   the one that seemed so important to you, that you adopted the name of
>   the Mule. We didn't foresee that you were not merely a mutant, but a
>   sterile mutant** and the added psychic distortion due to your
>   inferiority complex passed us by. We allowed only for a megalomania –
>   not for an intensely psychopathic paranoia as well.*
>
> <sub><sup>Second Foundation</sup></sub>

and

> *“Exactly, First Speaker. I wish I had thought of that expression. What was the Mule? A mutant. But where did he come from? How did he come to be? No one really knows. Might there not be more?”
>
>   “Apparently not. **The one thing that is best known about the Mule is that he was sterile. Hence his name.** Or do you think that is a myth?”*
>
> <sub><sup>Foundation's Edge</sup></sub>

Comment: It's been a while since I've read those books, but I recall having a sense that the "Mule" was very stubborn. Your quotes, though, appear to be conclusive.

Comment: @Shokhet That's just a great cover for his actual reason. People will imagine he calls himself the Mule because he's strong, stubborn, etc. It's just the usual megalomaniac puzzle for people to entirely misinterpret :) Also note that in later books, we learn a lot more about the origins of The Mule - he wasn't *really* a mutant.

Comment: @Luaan: I thought he was a mutant (hence why he was infertile), it's just that his powers don't come entirely from being a mutant.

Comment: @sumelic - Presumably he's just upset about the X-Men rejecting his application

Answer (score 41):

Because he's sterile, like most mules.

Comment: Damn, you type fast! :)

Comment: Include a lot of wavering on whether I should try and find textual evidence ... but it seems so obvious I don't think more evidence is needed.

Comment: @iayork evidence is always good. I've been surprised many times about things I thought were obvious.

Comment: @valorum got it before I could get home and check

Comment: @iayork I agree it's a very simple answer. I would select your answer for being correct as well if I could, but I felt it was just to go for the one with more detail.

Comment: @Calllack so did I

Comment: Like all mules, actually.

Comment: There are quite a few well-documented cases of fertile horse/donkey hybrids (mules and hinnies).